# AMP - access json data directly

Tags: amp-html

I want to access the JSON data directly from the json but i can't, i want the data without any events.

My AMP State-

```
<amp-state id="myState">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

My Element-

```
<p [text]="myState.foo">myState.foo</p>
```

Using text as an attribute needs an event to be fired for set the state. How to set the data directly.

Answer (score 1):

This [isn't possible](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-bind), you need some form of default state.

> NOTE — For performance and to avoid the risk of unexpected content jumping, amp-bind does not evaluate expressions on page load. This
>   means that the visual elements should be given a default state and not
>   rely amp-bind for initial render